# ServiceStack Ormlite Object column is not populated

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Using ServiceStack Ormlite 5.12.0.
I have a model looks like the following, saving the object is perfectly fine.

```
public string DescriptionAlias { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Applying PLUs (Price Lookup Code)
    /// Default is all
    /// </summary>
    [CustomField("LONGTEXT")]
    public Applying<string> ApplyingPlus { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Applying User Tags
    /// Default is all
    /// </summary>
    [CustomField("LONGTEXT")]
    public Applying<string> ApplyingUserTags { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Applying User Groups
    /// Default is all
    /// </summary>
    [CustomField("LONGTEXT")]
    public Applying<int> ApplyingUserGroups { get; set; }
```

[image]

When LoadSelect or Select the object, all Complex object Applying Columns are not populated.

Comment: If you can create a stand alone repro on GitHub or [gist.cafe](https://gist.cafe/#tutorial) I can take a look

Comment: @mythz looks like it is bug in 5.12.0. after upgrading to 6.1.0, the field is populated. thank you !